# How can I insert a table in a RichTextBox at a specific location

Tags: c#, wpf, replace, datatable, richtextbox

in my Richtextbox I have some Text. In the middle of the text are the string
[tabe=users]

how can I replace (ob Buttonpress) the string with my Table

I created a method which creates the Table

```
public static Table CreateTable(DataTable dataTable) {
    Table table = new Table();
    //convert DataTable to Table (with foreach) for RichTextbox //works fine
    return table;
}

//insert in the Bottom of the TextBox
RichTextBoxItem.Document.Blocks.Add(CreateTable(myDataTable));
```

I know, its possible to Add to a Paragraph, but it does not exist a specific paragraph <- its Hand written Text or CopyPaste Text from Word.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
RichTextBox theTable = new RichTextBox();
theTable.Document.Blocks.Add(CreateTable(thisDepTable));
byte[] theRichTable = GetRichContent(theTable);
```

at first a make an new RichTextBox an append the Table. Then I read the Content from the RichTextBox as bytecode. The Bytecode is possible to append in the right-place from the bytecode from my MainRichTextBox as Replacement.

If there a better way, I´m very interested